# Can Fed Funds Futures be seen as a Forward Rate Agreement?

Tags: interest-rates, futures, forward-rate

Fed Funds Futures trades the average Fed Funds rate for the contract month. Following the paper mentioned in [this answer](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/26192/30-day-federal-funds-futures-settlement-price/26193#26193), the rate implied by the contract can be compared to the term (forward) rate for the same month.
But can the implied rate be compared to a forward rate agreement, since the traded rate isn't a spot rate?

Comment: There are similarities but also differences. FRAs are not futures and rather trade OTC. The payoff of fed funds futures is based on an average rate in a month but there is no such averaging for FRAs.